# C (Arduino): treat a #defined hex value as ASCII chars

Tags: c, strings, sprint, hexadecimal

This is Arduino code, but since it uses C syntax, and it's not Arduino-specific, I thought I'd ask here. I have a few values defined so:

```
#define PID_RPM 0x0C
```

Typically it's used as a hex number. But in one spot, I need to print the last 2 chars ("0C") as literal 2 ASCII chars "0C". Right now I do it with a switch and an explicit string "0C":

```
switch(pid){
  case PID_RPM: OBD.println("0C"); break;
  ...
```

How can I convert the PID_RPM define to get its last 2 chars as literal ASCII? Maybe, instead of using a define, use char variables to store the hex PID values, then format them as a string with sprintf?

Comment: how about printing the number in hex? `OBD.printf("%02X", PID_RPM);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#` operator inside of a function-like macro will turn the argument into a string. If you do this twice, you can turn the macro expansion of the argument into a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MACRO_TO_STR(x) #x
#define EXPANSION_TO_STR(x) MACRO_TO_STR(x)
#define PID_RPM 0x0C

int main()
{
  printf("MACRO_TO_STR(PID_RPM) = %s\n", MACRO_TO_STR(PID_RPM));
  printf("EXPANSION_TO_STR(PID_RPM) = %s\n", EXPANSION_TO_STR(PID_RPM));
}
```

Here is the output:

```
MACRO_TO_STR(PID_RPM) = PID_RPM
EXPANSION_TO_STR(PID_RPM) = 0x0C
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds good. Can the expansion do a substring, too, i.e. get just the last two chars (the actual meaningful hex values)?

Comment: @MrSparkly, the macro expansion cannot create substrings. But if you want to print the value in hex, you can just use `printf("%02X", PID_RPM);`.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Thanks, everything works.

Comment: the macro expansion creates a string literal, so yes, you can access a substring of that string. For a simple case like this, yes `printf` is probably a better option